# image uploads getting wiped out after deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am using carrierwave for image uploads. I am storing the images at /public/uploads

When I deploy to heroku, images that were uploaded and saved previously are wiped out.

How can this be avoided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I can't upload images to heroku.

I have decided to use cloudinary for the time being.

I will probably switch to S3 eventually.